# Why using a circle in the definitions of interior points and boundary points

Tags: set-theory

In "*Thomas' Calculus: Early Transcendentals*" book, the author put forth this definition:

> A point $(x_{0} , y_{0})$ in a region (set) $R$ in the $xy$-plane is an interior point of $R$ if it is the center of a disk of positive radius that lies entirely in $R$. A point $(x_{0} , y_{0})$ is a boundary point of R if every disk centered at $(x_{0} , y_{0})$ contains points that lie outside of R as well as points that lie in $R$. (The boundary point itself need not belong to $R$.)

Is there anything special about using a circle in the definition because by simply inscribing the circle with a square (or even an equilateral triangle), we can have the same definition?

Comment: If you want to abstract this definition you can.   $\exists \epsilon$ such that every point with distance from $(x_0,y_0) < \epsilon$ is in $R$ would be an equivalent definition (using Euclidean distance).  But then you could use a different distance metric.  e.g. If you use the taxicab distance, "circles are squares."

Comment: This is quite an astute question/observation. No, there is nothing special about circular discs, and square discs would perform the same function. This kind of thing is considered in more detail when learning about topology - the set of circular discs forms a *basis for the topology* on $\Bbb{R}^2$, as does the set of squares. In other words, you get the same definition of interior and boundary regardless of whether you use circles or squares.

Comment: @user317176 though you do need a sensible metric for distance: the discrete metric (every distance which is not $0$ is $1$) would not work

Comment: @Henry Indeed, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is nothing special about using a circle, and you could have used a square or a triangle surrounding $(x_0, y_0)$.

The reason a circle is used is because you need to use *some* shape, and a circle is in some sense the easiest one to describe, and one that naturally generalizes (in every situation where you have an idea of "distance", you can define what a disc is).

Answer (score 2):

Inside every circle centered at $p$, you can draw an equilateral triangle centered at $p$, and vice versa. It is not difficult to use this to show that the notion of interior, exterior and boundary defined using one shape is equivalent to what you get if you use the other shape to define the same notions. There is no theoretical impact of using one over the other. You could even allow both of them at the same time. The only reason to choose is convenience.

Circles are most common. I would guess it's because they are so very symmetric. They emphasise and play nicely with the fact that the Euclidean plane has no inherent orientation, only a notion of distance. Squares and rectangles seem to be second most popular, presumably because they work well with the coordinates people invariably impose on their planes.