# Is there a metric on the plane for which (unit) circles are triangles?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

If we use the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^2$, (unit) circles are circles; if we use the Manhattan distance or $\ell^1$ distance, (unit) circles are squares. We can also get polygons with an even number of sides: for instance, circles are hexagons if we define the distance between two points to be the shortest path between them that moves only along the directions of the sides of some fixed triangle.

Is there a metric on $\mathbb R^2$ (that gives the usual topology) for which circles, or at least unit circles, are triangles?

(This question is inspired by though unrelated to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4768898/why-using-a-circle-in-the-definitions-of-interior-points-and-boundary-points/4768903#4768903).)

Comment: Not sure if there is such a metric, but definitely there is no norm whose unit ball is a triangle, because unit balls have to be balanced sets.

Comment: Do you allow nonsymmetric metrics?

Comment: @MoisheKohan if you allow that the answer is yes (e.g. orient the edges of the triangle from the hexagon example clockwise, and only allow paths that follow edges along their orientation); my question is about "ordinary" metrics.

Comment: The question can be answered by finding a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ which maps unit circles to unit triangles. Such homeomorphism of course exists. It needs to be the identity over 3 rays (starting at the origin), and a bit of squeezing elsewhere.

Comment: @freakish: **every** unit circle to a triangle? How do you construct such a map? What you outlined is very far from an actual construction. I am not sure it exists.

Comment: @MoisheKohan sorry, I meant every circle with $0$ as its origin.

Comment: But then this does not answer the posed problem, especially because there is only one unit circle centered at the origin.

Comment: @MoisheKohan that's why it is just a comment.

Comment: Something like $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \max ((x_2-x_1) +(y_2 - y_1), (x_2-x_2) - (y_2-y_1), y_2 - y_1)$ should work, but I haven't fully tested it.

Comment: @user317176, I think there are some typoes in what you wrote, but I don't know how I would fix it in a way that would make the function a metric.

Comment: @user317176: This approach is hopeless, see the first comment.

Comment: @MeesdeVries where I have $(x_2-x_2),$ I should have $(x_2-x_1)$  However, it does satisfy the axioms of a metric, and the locus of points one unit away form a right triangle.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  A norm implies a metric and a balanced set in the unit ball.  But, we can define a metric that is not infered from a metric and does not have a ballanced set as its unit ball.

Comment: @user317176 your metric is not a metric according to the usual definition, as it can be negative, if for example $x_2-x_1=-2$, and $y_2-y_1=-1$.  Likewise it is not symmetric.

Comment: @MW  another transcription error... should be $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \max ((x_2-x_1) +(y_2 - y_1), (x_2-x_1) - (y_2-y_1), x_1 - x_2)$  Thanks....

Comment: @user317176 my previous example still shows this is not symmetric

Comment: @MW I see the problem, now.  Thanks.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Interesting question. I guess we can generalize it, and ask whether there is also a metric for which unit circles are other (regular) $n$-sided polygons.

Comment: @MaxMuller, the answer for $2n$-sided polygons is "yes"; to get a $2n$-sided polygons take as distance between two points the shortest path that only walks in the directions $((\cos(k \pi / n), \sin(k \pi / n))$. I am pretty sure the answer for odd-sided polygons other than triangles is "no" -- at least in the sense of "all unit balls are congruent regular polygons" -- but I haven't worked out the details of that argument and it does not apply to triangles. (The argument in few words: start with any one unit "circle", and then look where the unit "circles" around its vertices must go; repeat.)

Comment: Since $\Bbb C\simeq \Bbb R^2$ it seems to me that you can solve this problem by using a conformal map.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri: How it can possibly help? The answer to the OP is most likely negative but is hard to prove.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, it was just a hazy intuition: suppose $\Phi$ maps the unit circle on the equilateral triangle with unit length side. Now consider the map $\nu(z)$ defined  as $z\mapsto \dfrac{z}{\|z\|}$ and the parametric map $r(z,\zeta)$ defined as $(z,\zeta)\mapsto \|z\|\zeta$. Then the map $z\mapsto r\Big(z,\Phi\big(\nu(z)\big)\Big)$ maps circles of any radius in equilateral triangles that have side length equal to that radius, but it seems it des not fulfill what is asked by the OP.